# pyppeteer - How to execute a javascript function that is inside the page?

Tags: python, pyppeteer

I have this element:

```
<span class="nc-lang-cnt" data-nc-lang="_errorNetwork" data-spm-anchor-id="0.0.0.i0.7e2a288airm7Er">
    Net Err. Please <a href="javascript:__nc.reset()">refresh</a><a href=""></a><a target="_blank" href=""></a>
</span>
```

I looks like this on a browser:

[image]

Here's my goal:

1. Check if a page shows that error
2. If the error appears, then click on that `refresh` button

How do I do it with pyppeteer ? I'm sorry for the stupid question, I'm still new to pyppeteer and python in general.